# Why no slope for a plane?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Similar to how lines have slopes defined in terms of $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$, why can't planes have slopes defined in therms of $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$, and $\Delta z$?

Couldn't these could be represented in terms of a vector: $$\left[ \begin{array}{c} \Delta x \\ \Delta y \\ \Delta z \end{array} \right]$$

Why is instead of a slope of a plane is its normal vector used instead? Couldn't an equation of a plane be derived from the vector of $\Delta x$, and $\Delta y$ and $\Delta z$ instead of from the normal vector?

Comment: If $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, then the gradient of $z(x, y)$ is a constant vector in 2 dimensions which determines the plane (up to translating), which sounds like what you want. That doesn't work for planes like, say, $x+y=3$, which can't be solved for $z$.

Comment: A non-vertical line has equation $y = mx + b$, where $m$ is the slope of the line.  A non-vertical hyperplane has equation $y = \langle m, x \rangle + b$, and the vector $m$ is the slope of the hyperplane.  Just as the derivative is the slope of the tangent line, the gradient is the slope of the tangent hyperplane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A point and a normal vector is a convenient parameterization for a plane because it is coordinate-independent. Sometimes planes are parameterized by a point and a gradient ("slope") instead, for instance you can represent the plane

$$z = ax+by+c$$

with the point $(1,1,a+b+c)$ and gradient $\nabla_{x,y}z = (a,b)$. But notice that this requires choosing a preferred direction -- in this case, the $z$ direction. A normal vector does not require you to make such a choice.

Comment: If you take the directional derivative you essentially get the slope in the form of a vector $<\Delta x,\; \Delta y,\; \Delta z>$ in your chosen direction right?

Comment: Directional derivative of what? If you mean the directional derivative of $z(x,y)$ in the direction $(u,v)$ is $\nabla_{x,y}z \cdot (u,v)$, then yes.

Comment: @user7530 sorry to revive this, but, is there a way to tell if this gradient of the hyperplane is pointing upwards (+ "slope") or downwards (- "slope")? Like how would you figure out the sign of this gradient?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question... however all will be answered in Integral Calculus. :P A simple explanation is that you are now in 3D space. A plane is flat, so you use instead a "normal vector" which is perpendicular to the plane for these types of calculations.

Look up how gradients and planes are used to calculate slope, it'll explain everything.