# Slope of a hyperplane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-geometry

I was reading a book (Nonlinear Elliptic Equations of the Second Order by Qin Han), and there was something which I didn't really understand. I will try to simply the setting for my question.

Let $a\in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}.$

We consider the function $\ell(x)=M - a\cdot x$, where $M$ is a positive constant and $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Then the graph of $\ell$ shall be a hyperplane (in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$) passing through the point $(0,M)$, where $0\in \mathbb R^n$.

The author wrote that, the graph of $\ell$ has the slope $a$, which I didn't understand.

I have two questions.

Q1: I looked up on MSE and someone said that the gradient is just the slope (of a plane), cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712763/507382. Is this the definition of the slope of a plane? Why does it make sense geometrically?

Q2: Intuitively, $\nabla \ell= -a$, and the graph of $\ell$ shall have the slope $-a$, which is not $a$ as he said?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Offhand I don't recall seeing the term "slope" being used for a normal to a hyperplane; on the other hand, given what the author wrote I'd assume that _is_ a definition of "slope" unless there's reason not to. <> If $a$ is normal to a hyperplane, so is $-a$, or $\lambda a$ for every non-zero $\lambda$; if we speak of _the_ slope, uniqueness must be understood as _up to scalar multiplication_.

Comment: It is a sloppy use of terminology. $a$ does determine how the hyperplane is inclined, but in good ole $\Bbb R^2$, it doesn't correspond well to the concept of slope we are accustomed to. As Andrew D. Hwang has said, $a$ is a normal vector to the hyperplane. However, if some coordinate $a_i \ne 0$, the various ratios $\frac{a_k}{a_i}$ for $k \ne i$ are the slopes of the intersections of the hyperplane with the $k$-$i$ planes. So while it serves the same purpose as slope, it also has its differences.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks for the comment. I have a question. Let us simplify the case by letting $M=0$. Then $\ell(x)=-a\cdot x$ and the graph of $\ell$ is $\{(x, \ell(x)) | \forall x\in \mathbb R^n\}$. If we let $z$-axis be $\mathbb R$ and $x,y$-plane be $\mathbb R^n$, and we draw the graph of $\ell$ in the $xyz$ system, then the graph is a hyperplane with an acute angle between itself and the $xy$-plane. Note that $a$ is on the $xy$-plane. How do we see that $a$ is normal to the hyperplane? Thanks.

Comment: My oops: The use of $a$ in the second part of my comment doesn't match the usage in your question. Instead, the normal to the hyperplane is $(a, 1)$ viewed as an element of $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$. It _does_ sort of make sense to call $a$ a "slope" (up to a sign it generalizes the slope of a line in the plane), though now I don't understand the choice of sign. <> If that helps, please do type up your own answer!